# SQL functions supported by ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, sql, ogr2ogr, sqlite

I have a GeoJSON, `test.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.34, 56.78 ] } }
]
}
```

I would like to swap the coordinates using [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html). After Googling a bit, I arrive to the [`ST_FlipCoordinates`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_FlipCoordinates.html) function:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_FlipCoordinates(geometry) as geometry FROM test" test_swapped_coords.geojson test.geojson
```

resulting in the error:

> ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT
> ST_FlipCoordinates(geometry) as geometry FROM test):   no such
> function: ST_FlipCoordinates

After more trial and error, I realize I can solve my problem via:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT SwapCoordinates(geometry) as geometry FROM test" test_swapped_coords.geojson test.geojson
```

giving me `test_swapped_coords.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "SELECT",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 56.78, 12.34 ] } }
]
}
```

---

`SwapCoordinates` works, `ST_FlipCoordinates` does not work. This leads me to the question:

**How can I know which SQL functions are supported by `ogr2ogr`?**

and which `-dialect` I need to be in if I want to use them. If there is a list somewhere, or I need to look at a particular place within the source code, that would work. I would like to know where to look.

Comment: fairly certain it uses whatever the sqllte geometry functions are available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [doc](https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html#spatialite-sql-functions) says:

> The syntax of the SQL statements is fully the one of the SQLite SQL
> engine.

and

> Spatialite SQL functions
>
> When GDAL/OGR is build with support for the Spatialite library, a lot
> of extra SQL functions, in particular spatial functions, can be used
> in results column fields, WHERE clauses, etc….

and it includes a link to the [spatialite functions](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the non-geometry columns, one can refer to the list of SQLite functions:

https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html